# How to do a proper HQL join

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hql

Hi StackOverflow Community,

I am having trouble with an HQL query. For a financial application, we want to get a TradeTicket entity based on a given StrategyInstrument entity. Here are the defined entities (details omitted, only relationships shown).

```
@Entity
public class Trade {
    @ManyToOne
    private Ticket ticket;

    @ManyToOne
    private Order buyOrder;

    @ManyToOne
    private Order sellOrder;
    ...
}

@Entity 
public class TradeTicket {
    private Date modifiedDateTime;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Order {
    @OneToOne
    private StrategyInstrument strategyInstrument;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class StrategyInstrument {
    ...
}
```

And I attempt the following query:

```
String queryString = "select ticket from TradeTicket ticket"
    + " join Trade trade"
    + " join Order order"
    + " where trade.tradeTicket = ticket"
    + " and (trade.buyOrder = order or trade.sellOrder = order)"
    + " and order.strategyInstrument = :strategyInstrument"
    + " and ticket.clearingApproval.approved = true"
    + " order by ticket.modifiedDateTime";
List<TradeTicket> results = getSession()
    .createQuery(queryString)
    .setParameter("strategyInstrument", strategyInstrument)
    .list();
```

Which results in the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: Order near line 1, column 102 [select ticket from com.mycompany.model.transactional.TradeTicket ticket join Trade trade   join Order order where trade.tradeTicket = ticket and (trade.buyOrder = order or trade.sellOrder = order) and order.strategyInstrument = :strategyInstrument and ticket.clearingApproval.approved = true order by ticket]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:284)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1760)
```

Any clues as to what is wrong with my HQL?

Thanks,

Jose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These guys are correct, `Order` is reserved but don't change your entity name try using backticks in the definition of that table.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="`Order`")
public class Order {`
```

Source:
[Hibernate Jira](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3811)

Answer (score 1):

`order` is a reserved JPQL and SQL keyword. Change the name of your entity.

Your syntax is also wrong. joins in HQL use associations between entities. The correct syntax is for example

```
select ticket from Trade trade
join trade.ticket ticket
```

Comment: But we are using the Order entity in other HQL statements, and we do not encounter any issues there.

Answer (score 0):

`Order` is a reserved word; try using something else.